# "libreadline" bugs getting in the way of bash scripts?

Tags: macos, bash, dylib, libreadline

I was trying to convert a bash script to binary using shc. I put in a colored help page like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    echo -e "\e[0;31m———————————————\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[0;33m  Script help \e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[0;31m———————————————\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[0;34mOPTIONS\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[1;33m--help\e[0m"
    echo -n "   "
    echo -e "\e[0;33mAccess this help page.\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[0;31m———————————————\e[0m"
    exit 0
fi
```

When I tested it normally, it was working fine all the time. But then I converted it to binary with `shc -T -f script`, and now every other time I run `./script.x --help` it gives me this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /bin/bash
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib: open() failed with errno=24
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What happened?

Comment: Are you using OS X or is this about iOS? I might have gotten the tag wrong, and it is important to know which OS you are using.

Comment: Error 24 in OSX is "EMFILE", which means "too many open files". You might be able to change the limit with `ulimit -n`. Apparently, the OSX open file limit is quite low, but I have no idea why trying to start up bash would exceed that limit.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the "compiled" script is playing games with temporary files/etc. before it spawns a shell to run the "compiled" code.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Quite possible, but even so using 64 FDs seems a bit extravagant. Of course, it's quite possible that the dynamic loader is also careless about how many fds it uses.

Comment: Alright, so `ulimit -n` echoes back 256, and the script doesn't interact with any temporary files. Weird.

Comment: Also, apparently OS X doesn't allow `ulimit -n <limit>`.

Comment: Update: `sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65000` fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if anyone else is reading this with the same problem, I found a solution:
`sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65000`
It's apparently an alternative of `ulimit -n` that OS X allows. But it's still a mystery as to why it's necessary in the first place...